# how can I view the list of arguments that a flutter widget accepts in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, mobile-development

[this is an example of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TNnp.png)

I want to view this list without typing any letter, is it possible?
i am using Mac not Windows

Comment: try ctrl+space ....

Comment: if you are using mac, then use: command + space

Answer (score 4):

This is the shortcut in **Android Studio**  and **VS Code**
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: is it the same on mac?

Comment: @AliMazen Yes. Just be sure to really use the "Control" button and not the "command".

Answer (score 1):

You can view the widget's code to see all the arguments it takes.

hold `Ctrl` button and click on the widget to view the code.